# How to add a custom prefix in a << operator for a custom object

Tags: c++

Is there a way to add a custom prefix in the `operator<<` for an object that I implement?

Ex:

```
class A {
   public:
    std::string id;
    int count;
};

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const A &a)
{
    os << os.prefix() << "Id: " << a.id << "\n";
    os << os.prefix() << "Count: " << a.count << "\n";
    return os;
}
```

If I do something like this:

```
A a;
a.id = "foo";
a.count = 1;
std::cout << a << std::endl;
```

The output will be:

```
Id: foo
Count: 1
```

I want to do something like:

```
std::cout << set_prefix(" -") << a << std::endl;
std::cout << set_prefix("==>") << a << std::endl;
```

To get an output like this:

```
 -Id: foo
 -Count: 1
==>Id: foo
==>Count: 1
```

A suggestion is to use `std::setfill` and `os.fill`, but `std::setfill` takes a single `char` as an argument and I need a custom string instead.

## Solution

Looking at [operator<<(std::basic_ostream)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) documentation, I found this:

> Before insertion, first, all characters are widened using
>   `os.widen()`, then padding is determined as follows: if the number of
>   characters to insert is less than `os.width()`, then enough copies of
>   `os.fill()` are added to the character sequence to make its length
>   equal `os.width()`. If `(out.flags()&std::ios_base::adjustfield) ==
>   std::ios_base::left`, the fill characters are added at the end of the
>   output sequence, otherwise they are added before the output sequence.
>   After insertion, `width(0)` is called to cancel the effects of
>   `std::setw`, if any.

So the solution that works for me was save the original width of stream at the beggining and than recovering them when necessary.

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const A &a)
{
    auto w = os.width();
    os << std::setw(w) << "" << "Id: " << a.id << "\n";
    os << std::setw(w) << "" << "Count: " << a.count;
    return os;
}
```

Then:

```
std::cout << a << std::endl;
std::cout << std::setw(4) << a << std::endl;
std::cout << std::setfill('>') << std::setw(2) << a << std::endl;
```

Gave the following output:

```
Id: foo
Count: 1
    Id: foo
    Count: 1
>>Id: foo
>>Count: 1
```

Comment: why not add the `-` in your `operator<<`, not really clear what is the problem...

Comment: @user463035818 Think of it this way: the OP wants to have a custom io-manipulator which prefixes each line with some string.

Comment: @Justin yeah sometimes I need a snarky comment to start thinking :P

Comment: The mechanism for doing this kind of thing is `std::ios_base::xalloc`, `std::ios_base::iword`, and `std::ios_base::pword`. The first gives a unique index that can be passed to either of the latter two functions to get a reference to a stored `long` value (`iword`) or a stored `void*` value (`pword`). You can then write a manipulator to store the appropriate text (by allocating a char array, and storing its address through `pword`); your stream inserter can then call `pword` to get the stored text. If someone wants to write an example of how to do this, that would be a good answer.

Comment: @PeteBecker Oh yeah, storing a pointer to plain `char[]` array would have been better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know of any way to do this with a string, but if you are content with just a char, it looks like you can use `std::setfill` manipulator, and than in your overload use the fill character:

```
std::cout << std::setfill('-') << a << std::endl;

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const A &a)
{
    os << os.fill() << "Id: " << a.id << "\n";
    os << os.fill() << "Count: " << a.count << "\n";
    return os;
}
```

Comment: In fact I resolved the problem with a variation of this solution, explained in the question.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a bit of overkill, but you can use something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

struct line_buffered_stream {
    std::ostream& out;
    std::stringstream ss;
    std::string prefix;
    line_buffered_stream(std::ostream& out,std::string prefix) : 
        out(out),prefix(prefix) {}        
    template <typename T> 
    auto operator<<(const T& t) -> decltype(this->ss << t,*this) { 
        ss << t; 
        return *this;
    }        
    ~line_buffered_stream(){
        std::string line;
        while (std::getline(ss,line)){
            out << prefix << line << "\n";
        }
    }
};

int main() {
     line_buffered_stream(std::cout,"==>") << "a\nb\n";
     line_buffered_stream(std::cout,"-->") << "a\nb\n";        
}
```

output:

```
==>a
==>b
-->a
-->b
```

[Live Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/8RmBzSoStIz98YTo)

Note that the implementation above is not meant to be used as anything else than a temporary whose lifetime is restricted to a single line of code. If you dont like that you'd have to add some mechanism to flush the stream to `std::cout` not to wait till the destructor is called.

Comment: I do  not like templated omnivorous `<<`. It is defined for everything, but underlying stream's `<<` might not be defined for it. This can break sfinae, and in unpleasant way.

Comment: I would expression-template-sfinae it. The code wouldn't fit into the comment, but I can post an answer, if you want

Comment: @SergeyA give me a minute I am working on it. I'll come back to your offer in case I dont manage ;)

Comment: @SergeyA took me a bit longer than expected.. tried to write a `has_output_operator<T>` to use `enable_if` but I failed miserably, openend a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52617204/error-functional-cast-to-array-type-while-trying-to-detect-if-stdcout-is-vali)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a big fan of this because it uses a global variable but that does allow you to have other classes use this same method, they just have to write thier own `operator <<` correctly.  It also requires that you call `set_prefix("");` when you want to clear the prefix from printing.  That said it does allow you to prepend any string you want to the output.

```
namespace details
{
    // we neeed this for tag dispatch
    struct Prefix {};
    // this will be used in the class(es) operator << for the line prefix
    std::string prefix;
    // allows set_prefix to be called in the output stream by eating it return and returning the stream as is
    std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, const Prefix& prefix)
    {
        return os;
    }
}

// set the prefix and return a type that allows this to be placed in the output stream
details::Prefix set_prefix(const std::string& prefix)
{
    details::prefix = prefix;
    return {};
}

class A {
   public:
    std::string id;
    int count;
};

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const A &a)
{
    os << details::prefix << "Id: " << a.id << "\n";
    os << details::prefix << "Count: " << a.count << "\n";
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.id = "foo";
    a.count = 1;
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << set_prefix(" -") << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << set_prefix("==>") << a << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
Id: foo
Count: 1

 -Id: foo
 -Count: 1

==>Id: foo
==>Count: 1
```

Comment: The biggest issue here, of course, is the fact that it is the same prefix for ALL streams, which runs contrary to normal manipulators. I contemplated this approach, but didn't post it, because there is not 100% way to make it work like normal manipulator - you could attempt to have a map of stream object addresses and prefixes, but you can easily have two objects sharing the same address at different times. You would also usually call private namespace `detail` (lacks S) and my personal preference would be to set the variable inside operator, not function call.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to store custom data on a stream object, but it isn't pretty: the [`iword`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iword) and [`pword`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/pword) interfaces.

### stream_prefix.hpp:

```
#ifndef STREAM_PREFIX_HPP_
#define STREAM_PREFIX_HPP_

#include <utility>
#include <string>
#include <ostream>

namespace stream_prefix_details {
    class set_prefix_helper {
    public:
        explicit set_prefix_helper(std::string prefix)
            : m_prefix(std::move(prefix)) {}
    private:
        std::string m_prefix;

        // These insertion operators can be found by Argument-Dependent Lookup.
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(
            std::ostream&, set_prefix_helper&&);
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(
            std::ostream&, const set_prefix_helper&);
    };
}

// The set_prefix manipulator. Can be used as (os << set_prefix(str)).
inline auto set_prefix(std::string prefix)
    -> stream_prefix_details::set_prefix_helper
{ return stream_prefix_details::set_prefix_helper{ std::move(prefix) }; }

// Get the prefix previously stored by (os << set_prefix(str)), or
// an empty string if none was set.
const std::string& get_prefix(std::ostream&);

#endif
```

### stream_prefix.cpp:

```
#include <stream_prefix.hpp>

namespace stream_prefix_details {
    int pword_index() {
        static const int index = std::ios_base::xalloc();
        return index;
    }

    void stream_callback(std::ios_base::event evt_type,
                         std::ios_base& ios, int)
    {
        if (evt_type == std::ios_base::erase_event) {
            // The stream is being destroyed, or is about to copy data
            // from another stream. Destroy the prefix, if it has one.
            void*& pword_ptr = ios.pword(pword_index());
            if (pword_ptr) {
                delete static_cast<std::string*>(pword_ptr);
                pword_ptr = nullptr;
            }
        } else if (evt_type == std::ios_base::copyfmt_event) {
            // The stream just copied data from another stream.
            // Make sure we don't have two streams owning the same
            // prefix string.
            void*& pword_ptr = ios.pword(pword_index());
            if (pword_ptr)
                pword_ptr =
                    new std::string(*static_cast<std::string*>(pword_ptr));
        }
        // Can ignore imbue_event events.
    }

    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os,
                             set_prefix_helper&& prefix_helper)
    {
        void*& pword_ptr = os.pword(pword_index());
        if (pword_ptr)
            *static_cast<std::string*>(pword_ptr) =
                std::move(prefix_helper.m_prefix);
        else {
            os.register_callback(stream_callback, 0);
            pword_ptr = new std::string(std::move(prefix_helper.m_prefix));
        }
        return os;
    }

    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os,
                             const set_prefix_helper& prefix_helper)
    {
        void*& pword_ptr = os.pword(pword_index());
        if (pword_ptr)
            *static_cast<std::string*>(pword_ptr) = prefix_helper.m_prefix;
        else {
            os.register_callback(stream_callback, 0);
            pword_ptr = new std::string(prefix_helper.m_prefix);
        }
        return os;
    }
}

const std::string& get_prefix(std::ostream& os)
{
    void* pword_ptr = os.pword(stream_prefix_details::pword_index());
    if (pword_ptr)
        return *static_cast<std::string*>(pword_ptr);
    else {
        // This string will never be destroyed, but it's just one object.
        // This avoids the Static Destruction Order Fiasco.
        static const std::string* const empty_str = new const std::string;
        return *empty_str;
    }
}
```

#### Usage:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stream_prefix.hpp>

class A {
   public:
    std::string id;
    int count;
};

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const A &a)
{
    os << get_prefix(os) << "Id: " << a.id << "\n";
    os << get_prefix(os) << "Count: " << a.count << "\n";
    return os;
}

int main() {
    A a;
    a.id = "foo";
    a.count = 1;
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << set_prefix("==> ") << a << std::endl;
}
```

Full working demo [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b0180f70ebf26399).

Note this `set_prefix` manipulator is "sticky", meaning the setting will remain on the stream after use, like most of the standard manipulators except for `std::setw`.  If you want it to reset after you're done outputting an `A` object description, just add `os << set_prefix(std::string{});` to the `operator<<` function.

Answer (score 0):

This works, but it is very, very ugly and terrible code.

Couple of issues:
- operator<< has to be defined outside of the class, because you want to take in class A as the rhs argument, instead of invoking it like A::operator<<() - and actually taking in a second A class as an argument.
- cout cannot deal with a void output, so because you insist on chaining setting the prefix with the cout commant, it has to return an empty string object.
- If you don't want the prefix to be remembered, just do prefix.clear() at the end of the operator<< definition.

```
    class A
    {
    public:
         std::string id;
         std::string prefix;
         int count;

         std::string set_prefix(const std::string& inp) 
         {
              prefix = inp;
              return std::string();
         }


         std::string get_prefix() const
         {
              return prefix;
         }

    };

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const A &input)
{

    os << input.get_prefix() << "Id: " << input.id << "\n";
    os << input.get_prefix() << "Count: " << input.count << "\n";
    return os;
}


int main()
{
     A class1;
     class1.id = "test";
     class1.count = 5;
     std::cout << class1.set_prefix(" -") << class1; // endl removed, as your operator<< definition already has a "\n" at the end.
     std::cout << class1.set_prefix("==>") << class1;
}
```