# error: functional cast to array type while trying to detect if std::cout << t; is valid

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, sfinae

Triggered by a comment to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52561966/4117728) I would like to write (in C++11) a

```
template <typename T>
struct has_out_op { static const bool value = ???; }
```

to dis/enable a member function depending on `std::cout << t;` being valid for some `T t`. I came this far...

```
#include <iostream>

struct can_convert_to_base{}; // but does not when there is a better match
struct base {base(can_convert_to_base);};

template <typename T> 
auto test(const T& t,can_convert_to_base) 
-> decltype( std::cout << t);

template <typename T> 
std::false_type test(const T& t,base);

template <typename T>
struct has_out_op {
    static const bool value = 
        !std::is_same<std::false_type,
                      decltype( test(T(),can_convert_to_base()) )
                      >::value;
};

struct A{};

int main() {
    std::cout << has_out_op<int>::value;   // prints 1
    std::cout << has_out_op<A>::value;     // prints 0
}
```

This seems to work, but when I use it for what I was actually aiming for:

```
struct B {
    template <typename T>
    typename std::enable_if<has_out_op<T>::value,B&>::type operator<<(const T& t)  {
        std::cout << t;
        return *this;
    }
};
int main() {
    B b;
    b << "1";
}
```

I get the error

```
prog.cc: In instantiation of 'const bool has_out_op<char [2]>::value':
prog.cc:25:60:   required by substitution of 'template<class T> typename std::enable_if<has_out_op<T>::value, B&>::type B::operator<<(const T&) [with T = char [2]]'
prog.cc:31:14:   required from here
prog.cc:17:67: error: functional cast to array type 'char [2]'
                           decltype( test(T(),can_convert_to_base()) )
                                                                   ^
prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
prog.cc:31:11: error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'B' and 'const char [2]')
         b << "1";
           ^
```

Then I realized that my `has_out_op` requires `T` to be default constructible, and since that I am turning in circles. When I have a value I can easily `test` if `std::cout << t;` is valid, but with the type alone I have no idea how to properly implement `has_out_op`.

**How to detect if there is a matching overload for `std::cout << t;` given only `decltype(t)`?**

Note that I already know how to dis/enable `B::operator<<` properly, but out of courisity I am still struggling with getting `has_out_op` right.

Comment: (reading in diagonal) is `std::declval<T>()` what you want?

Comment: @bolov if it works for non default constructible `T` or any other restrictrions then yes thats exactly what I am looking for

Comment: Note there's no easy way to make `struct B` work with `std::endl` and several other standard manipulators, because they are actually function templates, and a template argument can't be deduced from a function argument that names a function template.

Comment: Usually if you're tempted to make a stream-like class that does something that can be described at the byte level, the best answer is instead to derive from `std::streambuf`, and stick your custom buffer into a plain `ostream` (or `istream` etc.). This was described in James Kanze's classic article "Filtering Streambufs", and Boost.Iostreams often makes it easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`std::declval<T>()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval) to the rescue:

> Converts any type `T` to a reference type, making it possible to use
>   member functions in `decltype` expressions **without the need to go
>   through constructors**.
>
> Note that because no definition exists for declval, it can only be
>   used in unevaluated contexts; i

```
 ...
 decltype( test(std::declval<T>(),can_convert_to_base()) )
 ...
```

---

Since we're already here, your solution is overly complicated. This is how I would do it:

```
struct B {
    template <typename T, class = decltype(std::cout << std::declval<T>())>
    B& operator<<(const T& t)
    {
        std::cout << t;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

---

> though I would be interested if there is a simpler solution for
>   has_out_op

```
template <typename T>
struct has_out_op_impl
{
    template <class U, class = decltype(std::cout << std::declval<U>())>
    static auto foo(U) -> std::true_type;

    static auto foo(...) -> std::false_type;

    using Type = decltype(foo(std::declval<T>()));
};

template <class T>
struct has_out_op : has_out_op_impl<T>::Type
{};

struct A{};

int t1()
{
    static_assert(has_out_op<int>::value == true, "");
    static_assert(has_out_op<A>::value == false, "");
}
```

Comment: Surprisingly simple. I was struggling to get my first sfinae running, now that it is working i feel like anything is possible :P Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user463035818 I've added a simpler solution :)

Comment: this is more or less what I had before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52561966/4117728) but this didnt really help me to get the hang of sfinae thats why I tried to write a `has_out_op`

Comment: though I would be interested if there is a simpler solution for `has_out_op` ;)

Comment: this solution is SFINAE. What was the problem?

Comment: there wasnt really a problem, just wanted to try a different approach for a better understanding

Comment: @user463035818 added another solution for `has_out_op`. Although I don't understand what you did with `can_convert_to_base`

Comment: There will be an easier solution if `is_detected` makes it from LfTS into the standard. In the meantime, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected for an implementation which works with C++11 too.

Comment: passing T to ... for generic T is not very safe

Comment: with `can_convert_to_base` I tried to ensure that the `false_type` overload is a better match when both are valid, ie to avoid ambiguity